# How to determine the actual usage of a malloc'ed buffer

Tags: c, malloc, size, compression

I have some compressed binary data and an API call to decompress it which requires a pre-allocated target buffer. There is not any means via the API that tells me the size of the decompressed data. So I can malloc an oversized buffer to decompress into but I would like to then resize (or copy this to) a memory buffer of the correct size. So, how do I (indeed can I) determine the actual size of the decompressed binary data in the oversized buffer?

(I do not control the compression of the data so I do not know in advance what size to expect and I cannot write a header for the file.)

Comment: Is that decompress API going to fail if you provide too small buffer? If it does, perhaps it will also tell you how big buffer you should provide? Give us more info if you want us to help you.

Comment: I'd really switch libraries since the one you are using is clearly bad.

Comment: You can't even get the size of the uncompressed data after uncompressing, e.g. like a return value from the uncomress function? What API are you using?

Comment: Why are you all people downvoting the question? It's a sucky API but not the OP's fault that s/he has to use it, and it's not an unreasonable thing to ask.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP does not understand the API. As stated it's beyond unusable. But FYI I'm not the downvoter.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, there is no good way to do this if your API doesn't provide it.

I almost don't want to suggest this for fear that you'll take this suggestion and have some mission-critical piece of your application depend on it, but...

A heurstic would be to fill your buffer with some 'poison' pattern before decompressing into it. Then, after decompression, scan the buffer for the first occurrence of the poison pattern.

This is a heuristic because it's perfectly conceivable that the decompressed data could just happen to have an occurrence of your poison pattern. Unless you have exact domain knowledge of what the data will be, and can choose a pattern specifically that you know cannot exist.

Even still, an imperfect solution at best.

Comment: Rather than scan the buffer for the first occurrence, scan backwards from the end until you don't see the poison pattern any more. At least you only hit problems if your decompressed data happens to *end* with the poison pattern rather than have it occur anywhere within the buffer.

Comment: To make this more robust, you could even do the decompression twice with two different poison patterns and verify that the end occurs at the same place. It's horrible, and depending on your constraints it won't give you any better performance than just keeping the original too-big buffer, but at least it might be a way out of a corner.

Comment: You would know for sure if you decompress twice, filling the buffer with 00 the first time and FF the second time.  But I'm certainly not advocating such a hack.

Comment: This approach, along with the improvement of decompressing twice, is definitely the best (and only?) solution to the problem as stated.

Comment: Thanks guys for all your comments. This was the answer I was anticipating and indeed fearing. The decompress function is actually a BIOS function of the device and accepts only the source buffer, dest buffer and compression type; the return is void. So I can either i) live with the oversized buffer, ii) do the hacky 'poison' pattern or iii) write my own decompression routine. I'll have to think about that...
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Usually this information is supplied at compression time (take a look at 7-zips LZMA SDK for example).

There is no way to know the actual size of the decompressed data (or the size of the part that is actually in use) with the information you are giving now.

Answer (score 0):

If the decompression step doesn't give you the decompressed size as a return value or "out" parameter in some way, you can't.

There is no way to determine how much data was written in the buffer (outside of debugger/valgrind-type checks).

Answer (score 0):

A complex way to answer this problem is by decompressing twice into an over-sized buffer.

In both cases, you need a "random pattern". Starting from the end, you count the number of bytes which correspond to the pattern, and detect the end of decompressed sequence where it differs.

Or does it ? Maybe, by chance, one of the final byte of the decompressed sequence corresponds to the random byte at this exact position. So the final decompressed size might be larger than the detected one. If your pattern is truly random, it should not be more than a few bytes.

You need to fill again the buffer with a random pattern, but a different one. Ensure that, at each position, ***the new random pattern has a different value than the old random pattern***. For faster speed, you are not obliged to fill the full buffer : you may limit the new pattern to a few bytes before and some more bytes after the 1st detected end. 32 bytes shall be enough, since it is improbable that so many bytes does correspond by chance to the first generated random pattern.

Decompress a second time. Detect again where the pattern differ. Take the larger of the two values between the first and second end detection. It is your decompressed size.

Answer (score -1):

you should check how free works for your compiler/os
and do the same. 
free doesn't take the size of the malloced data, but it somehow knows how much to free right ;)
usually the size is stored before the allocated buffer, don't know though exactly how maby bytes before again depending on the os/arch/compiler

Comment: This would have made a good comment, but as an answer... -1'd